# How to get values of controls inside ModalPopupExtender?

Tags: modalpopupextender

Hi I have a control with lots of textboxes and repeater inside a ModalPopupExtender how do i get those controls values?

Comment: You should provide more information. What programming language? What platform? Sample code?

Answer (score 0):

An example would be something like this:

```
((TextBox)SomePopupExtender.FindControl("SomeTextBox")).Text = "New Text";
```